# SSRS reports show repeating data from row above it

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I like using the out of the box table Wizard for SSRS.  However the default behavior is not showing repeating data from one row to another.  Is there a way to change that behavior?  For instance [image]

I would like Portland repeated twice instead of only showing up once.

Comment: seems you have created a grouping here. remove the grouping and you should be good. provide more details queries, RDL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first grouping column is **col1** and second numbered column is **col2**, 
do following steps:

1. Select **col2**
2. Insert a column on the left side of **col2** within the group
3. Select column source for that new column (the one that id displaying Portland?).
4. Run the report.
5. Once all looks good, remove **col1**.

If you want to keep the grouping, follow the steps from 1 to 5. otherwise, remove the group and related columns, and do the steps from  1 to 4.

Please let us know if that is not helping.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If your report has multiple row groups, you can group on multiple columns within the same group, and delete the other groups (group only). Also remember to suppress the page breaks, or you'll get one row per page.